# Debian, shell and jdk 8

Tags: debian, jdk

I'm trying to download jdk on debian 7 using wget command

```
wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gzw
```

I recieve "wget: unrecognized option '--header'". What am I doing wrong? Is there other way to install Jdk?

Answer (score 0):

To add the ppa:webupd8team/java PPA to your system's software sources and install Oracle Java 8 (both JDK8 and JRE8) in Debian 7 run the following commands from the terminal:

```
su -
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
apt-get update
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
exit
```

<sub>**Reference:** [How to install Oracle Java 8 in Debian via repository [JDK8]](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html)</sub>